# Bugs on deletion attribution, notification and tracking

Tags: bug, deletion

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/710059/242) was deleted 2 days ago because 3 users voted to delete the question, but the page wrongly claims that the answer was deleted 2 days ago *by the owner*. Browsing similar recent examples shows that the problem may be related to the fact that the answer had been temporarily deleted by the author sometime in the past (here 9 months ago).

Second, there was no notification of the deletion. It is not listed in the recently deleted answers page linked at the end of the owner's answers page. Update: Arthur found a [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492) answer which claims this list is limited to deleted answers that were posted in the last 60 days. Thus any older answer that is deleted is essentially under the radar. Why not treat older answers the same as newer answers? There is not necessarily any correlation between the quality of an answer and its age.

Is there any convenient way to monitor deletions?  The recent deletions list in the 10K tools overflows so quickly that one would need to check it a few times a days to see everything. Once a deletion disappears from this list it seems to be difficult to impossible to locate it again. Without better  checks and balances on deletions it becomes possible for a very small group of users (3) to exert unchecked control of site content.

Comment: I would guess that the fact that you had deleted this answer (and subsequently undeleted it) played a part in your being listed as the current deletion user. But that is clearly a bug. As for it not appearing in your "deleted recent answers", according to [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492) only posts made within the last 60 days will appear there. This part seems to be (status-bydesign).

Comment: @ArthurFischer Yes, that's my guess too after looking at similar cases.

Comment: What is the "recently deleted answers" page? I ask specifically as you wrote initially "deleted recent answers" (which is a page I know), yet then changed it. So I assume there might be something more to it than an oversight. If it is in fact an oversight I'd propose to change back to your original text. (Incidentally, in this case, the name already gives a hint regarding your second "bug.")

Comment: @quid The SE nomenclature is inconsistent. At the bottom of one's answer page is a link math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/<user-number>  i.e. "recently deleted answers" but the text says "deleted recent answers", etc. It seems  this feature is a work in progress. In any case, it makes no sense that the notification is given only if the *answer* was recent. It should be if the *deletion* was recent. Answers don't have lesser value because they are older.

Comment: Thanks for the explication. This makes some limited sense, though your priority is a bit strange as the visible text is the one you originally wrote, which is also written in bold and large letter across said page. But okay. On your last remark: to me it makes sense that only recent answers are there.